# How to use something similar to set (data.table) in sparklyr?

Tags: r, sparklyr

I have the following spark data frame called "clients":

```
ID    VAR1   VAR2   VAR3
 1      A      F      A1
 2      C      M      B1
 3      E      F      C1
 4      C      0      B1
```

And I also have a dictionary of variables called "ref", which shows the unique values a variable can take, like this one:

```
Variables     Values
VAR1          A
VAR1          B
VAR1          C
VAR1          D
VAR1          E
VAR2          F
VAR2          M
VAR3          A1
VAR3          B1
```

I want to replace those values that are not allowed for variables, with a default value like "-1", so I can have something like this:

```
    ID    VAR1   VAR2   VAR3
     1      A      F      A1
     2      C      M      B1
     3      E      F      -1
     4      C     -1      B1
```

With `data table` library I would use something like this:

```
names <- colnames(clients)

for(var in names){

set(x = clients,
    i = which(!clients[[var]] %in% ref[Variables == var]$Values),
    j = var,
    value = "-1")
```

I would like to know if there exist some similar solution to use with `sparklyr`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which functions are available for spark hence here is a base R option.

```
clients[-1] <- lapply(names(clients)[-1], function(x) {
                      replace(clients[[x]], 
                      !clients[[x]] %in% ref$Values[ref$Variables == x], NA)
                })

clients

#  ID VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
#1  1    A    F   A1
#2  2    C    M   B1
#3  3    E    F <NA>
#4  4    C <NA>   B1
```

I have replaced the values which are not allowed with `NA` instead of -1, you can use whichever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, similar to your current code, is to collect the list of `ref` values for each `VAR` and apply `case_when`. If the value exist in the collected list, return the value of `VAR`, otherwise return `-1`.

Let's see an example. I suggest to always provide code that generates the test dataset:

```
clients <- data.frame(
  ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  VAR1=c("A", "C", "E", "C"),
  VAR2=c("F", "M", "F", "0"),
  VAR3=c("A1", "B1", "C1", "B1"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ref <- data.frame(
  Variables = c("VAR1", "VAR1", "VAR1", "VAR1", "VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR2", "VAR3", "VAR3"),
  Values=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "M", "A1", "B1"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Start the session

```
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)
sc <- spark_connect(master="local[4]", version = "3.0.1")

sref <- copy_to(sc, ref)
sclients <- copy_to(sc, clients, overwrite = T)

for(var in c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3")) {
  var_values <- (sref %>% 
                   filter(Variables == var) %>% 
                   select(Values) %>% 
                   collect())$Values
  
  sclients <- sclients %>% 
    mutate(!!as.name(var) := case_when(!!as.name(var) %in% var_values ~ !!as.name(var),
                                       TRUE ~ "-1"))
}

sclients
```

Result

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 4]
     ID VAR1  VAR2  VAR3 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     F     A1   
2     2 C     M     B1   
3     3 E     F     -1   
4     4 C     -1    B1
```

Although this solution works, it may not be the best depending on how large your dataset is. For instance, if the values of `ref` for one `VAR` don't fit in memory, the collect will through an out of memory error. An alternative could be to generate an array column with the `ref` values and then check if the `VAR` value exist inside the array using a function like `hof_exists()`